# How can I make it so the first element in a DIV has a different CSS to others?

Tags: html, css, less

I have the following LESS code:

```
.modal-input-row {
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
        padding-top: 1rem;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;

        div {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;

            input {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                margin-bottom: 0.1rem;
                width: 75%;
            }

        }
    }
```

How can I make it so that the first modal-input-row inside an outer container does not have a padding at the top?

Comment: provide fiddle for it.

Comment: It depends on your markup, post the HTML as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:first-child` pseudoclass

```
.outercontainer .modal-input-row {
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;

    &:first-child {
       padding-top: 0;
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) represents the first element in children tree. It may or may not select the *first `.modal-input-row`*.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:first-child` pseudo-selector:

```
input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 0.1rem;
    width: 75%;
    &:first-child {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
}
```

However, if you want the `input` within your first `.modal-input-row` to have no top padding:

```
.modal-input-row {
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;

    div {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;

        input {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin-bottom: 0.1rem;
            width: 75%;
        }

    }
    &:first-child input {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on the markup. If there is only one input in each div element, then all of them will be treated by the selector.

Comment: Also `.modal-input-row:first-child` may not work as `:first-child` represents the first **element** in its parent, not the first *class*. As I said, it depends on the markup.