# How to target last-child

Tags: css, sass

Can't seem to target the last p-tag in my 3divs. I want to remove the border of the `last-child` of the `p`-tag. What am I doing wrong here:

```
      <div class="box">
        <div class="span4">
          <p>Some text.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
          <p>Some text.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
          <p>Some text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>      


.span4 {
    width: 320px;
    p {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        padding: 0 40px;
        border-right: 1px #dfdfdf solid;
    }
    &:last-child {
        border: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. Since I want to target a single p-tag in a div the solution is the following:

```
            .span4:last-child p{
                border-right: none;
            }
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to select the `p` tag with the pseudo-selector:

```css
.span4 {
    width: 320px;
    p {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        padding: 0 40px;
        border-right: 1px #dfdfdf solid;
        &:last-child {
            border: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And that is what I tought too, but that isn't the solution. The P tags are not behind each other (see my html example). I've found the solution.

Comment: -1 you're just ignoring [my comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22064704/how-can-i-make-it-so-the-first-element-in-a-div-has-a-different-css-to-others/22064762#comment33459234_22064762). It doesn't work as `p` is the only child of its parent `.span4`. it selects all the paragraphs!

Comment: Calm down guys, you edited your question after I was posting my answer. There was no html before.

Comment: Why are we bumping this to the top of the active questions by making trivial edits?